# Setting password expiry using chef 'user' resource

Tags: chef-infra

I am just trying to track down if it is possible to set the number of days before a users password is forced to changed (aka password expiry) using the Chef 'user' resource as per https://docs.chef.io/resource_user.html.

From my reading, it doesn't appear possible and that cheffers are creating their own cookbooks to do this.

Does anyone know how to do it, with "native" chef functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean the system user, that's completely OS-dependent, so giving a few details like the operating system would help.

Comment: As @KarenB said, it is system dependent, and not part of the user management. [os-hardening](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/os-hardening) cookbook have options to do this part. (more or less, managing login.defs on linux). Short answer: there's no native way with Chef.

Comment: Thanks @KarenB and Tensibai. It is for Ubuntu 12.04, and for an OS user.  But my question has pretty well been answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not available in the core `user` resource, which just uses `useradd` and `usermod` on Linux. You would have to install/script the `chage` command or set some defaults in `/etc/default/useradd` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I found a cookbook by Rackspace that seems to do what you need. It's an add-on, but it could work for what you need -- or for anyone who wandered here on a search like me.

https://github.com/rackspace-cookbooks/user_shadow